# VBA can't add pound sign to value

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro that prints the hours each work has done, but when i try in add each persons charge rate this works,

```
Dim name As Range
Dim nameRange As Range
Dim hours As Range
Dim price As Range

Set nameRange = Range("I:I")
Set name = Sheets("Home").Range("B12").Offset(i, 0)
Set price = Sheets("Home").Range("B12").Offset(i, 1)
Set hours = Range("G:G")

If Not IsEmpty(name) Then
With ActiveCell
    .Value = "Total No. of chargeable hours by " + name
    .Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(hours, nameRange, name)
    .Offset(0, 5).Value = price
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
End If
Next i
```

however when i change

```
.Offset(0, 5).Value = price
```

to

```
.Offset(0, 5).Value = "£" + price
```

i receive errors,

I have tried adding `.Style = "Currency"` to the line and that returns an error also. Am i missing something blatantly obvious? Thanks

Comment: `&` is for string concatenation not `+` : `"£" & price`

Comment: i shall change that then, but why does the first line `.Value = "Total No. of chargeable hours by " + name` work?

Comment: well it actually works for 2 strings but not for a string and a number. This is to enforce [strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a *String* use something like:

```
Sub StringMaker()
Dim price As Double
price = 12.5
With ActiveCell
    .Offset(0, 5).Value = "£" & price
End With
End Sub
```

and to create a *Formatted Number* use something like:

```
Sub NumberFormatter()
Dim price As Double
price = 12.5
With ActiveCell
    .Offset(0, 5).Value = price
    .Offset(0, 5).NumberFormat = "£" & "General"
End With
End Sub
```